# C++ read large text file

Tags: c++, performance

I have a very large text file for about 20GB. 
This file contains multiple text lines.

I need to read this file into the memory in chunks. Each chunk fits enough into the main memory.

What is the most efficient way to do that?
- read into buffers then parse data into C++ vector of char[].
- read file line by line and put into above vector
- or other way?

Comment: I do not believe that you have a 20GB text file. That aside - why not try either way and profile it. Or if it is a one off just let it run over the weekend for example

Comment: "C++ vector of char[]" -- please tell me you just mistyped and actually are aware of `std::string`, `std::vector`, and the evilness that is `char []`...

Comment: I just think that char array is faster than std::string.

Comment: For I/O buffers, don't bother with `std::vector` or `std::string`. Use an array of char.  Also, allocate it once and reuse it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have better idea to do that.

Comment: It is operating system and file system specific.

Comment: It also depends on how you're processing the contents of the file.  Do you jump around?  Do you use each byte in series and are then done with that byte?

Comment: @EdHeal Large text files aren't unheard of. I recently worked on a utility that had to process text files in excess of 100GB that were produced by a semiconductor design and verification tool.

Comment: Was those file unstructured?

Comment: they just contains lines of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient method is to read blocks or chunks of data into a buffer than scan the buffer.

The I/O has an overhead cost and the more data you can fetch per request, the better.

Searching in memory is always faster than reading one character at a time from the input.

Be aware of two cases:

1. A line continues past the end of your buffer.
2. The buffer is not filled up.

**Edit 1:  Memory Mapping**
Another alternative is to have the OS treat the file as memory.  Essentially, the OS will handle reading in chunks or blocks of the file as appropriate.

You will have to measure the performance (i.e. Profile), to find out which method is more efficient *and by how much*.

Comment: `std::ifstream` already does buffering. No point in adding another layer of buffering on top of that.

Comment: It's not a matter of buffering, but the size of the buffer.  For example, a self buffer scheme would allow a buffer of 512MB, whereas I don't believe `std::ifstream` uses that big of a buffer.  And yes, there are more buffers upstream from `std::ifstream`.

Comment: std::ifstream buffer is generalized for the best performance under **generic** situations (so it can be better for specific situations). But just give it a bigger buffer. No need to implement your own buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just adding some code to the answer:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const static size_t numToReadAtATime = 4;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream s{ "filename.dat" }; 

    while(true)
    {

        char nextChars[numToReadAtATime];

        if(s.readsome(nextChars, numToReadAtATime) != numToReadAtATime)
            break;

        //  dostuff with nextChars

    }

}
```